# How to handle exceptions from Camel splitter behind remote proxy

Tags: apache-camel

I have created a route that via a splitter does multiple lookups, aggregates the responses and returns the list of objects.

I use a remote proxy to invoke the route.

Given that there are multiple branches on the route it is possible that some will succeed and some will fail. How can I get all the returned results but also a list of failures, with reasons for failures, from the remote proxy?

I can think of 3 options, but hope there is something cleaner

1. Use a header structure that is passed in with remote proxy call to collect errors
2. Wrap the return value of the remote proxy in structure that contains results and errors
3. Route errors to some error endpoint (not sure how to correlate with my request though)

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with option 3. Route all the errors to a generic error endpoint where you log the errors and return some default response. That way you can refer to that generic error endpoint from all your branches ensuring they will all react the same way whenever they encounter an error.

Comment: Thank you for the info. How do I receive the errors in the class that invoked the remote proxy and not receive errors from parallel invocations of the remote proxy?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info of what you are after? The class that invoked the remote proxy will not be aware of the error, unless you save the error in your generic error endpoint in a property and then access that property from your invoking class.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get exception details in Aggregation strategy class and accordingly take action.

It depends on what you want to achieve from overall design. As a general practice, if you want consumer of your remote practice to fail on errors, it should get the exception details immediately. If your remote proxy is a REST Endpoint, it can return with 500 error. And similar strategy can be followed for other protocols.

Comment: Thank you for the info. How do I access the information from the class invoking the reverse proxy?
I want to return the information collected, but also see which of the routes failed.

Comment: I don't really understand what a reverse proxy is? So please help me with that. I can, however, answer the other question - If you use Aggregation strategy along with splitters - Aggregation strategy class will get aggregation output from all the split paths. This single aggregation strategy class will be responsible for all aggregates. In each invocation of the aggregation strategy class, u will get a newExchange and an oldExchange. These are your clues as to what is happening.

Comment: In case there is exception in the split path, newExchnage will have the following property`        Throwable caused = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);` .. You can this to figure out exception message and set the details in the exchange which is returned from the method. Now after aggregation, you can again check the details and figure out what exception actually occurred - or throw a new Exception - whatever your requirement is.

Comment: The information provide has been very helpful in clearing up how it works Can I access the information from a class that invokes a  camel remote proxy. The method signature is as follows

@Produces(url = "direct:collect-orders")
public Collection<Order> getOrders(Customer cust)

How can I see if orders from some of the sources failed? Can I access the Exchange somehow from the class invoking the remote proxy?

Comment: Yes.. Whatever headers you set on the exchange you return from Aggregation Strategy will be accessible from invoking class. So you can simply set appropriate headers in aggregation strategy and access them from invoking class. In case you don't have exchanges in invoking class - you can simply read the header and throw exception after aggregator component has ended.